# Get hour and minute difference between current time and 12pm

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get the current time difference in hours and minutes between now and 12pm (midday). If it is past 12pm on the current day it must then count down the hours onto the next day.

I have looked around here for a while now and have found many examples on getting date differences but and am unable to get a working solution for time so have been playing around with writing my own. However I am unable to `getTime();` to get hours and minutes from the millisecond timestamp on my new dates and am unsure why exactly. Here is my code:

```
dateone = new Date();
datetwo = new Date();
datetwo = datetwo.setHours(12);
dateone = dateone.getTime();
datetwo = datetwo.getTime();

if(dateone > datetwo) {
var seconds = dateone - datetwo;
} else {
var seconds = datetwo - dateone;
}

var d = seconds;
var minutes=(d/(1000*60))%60;
var hours=(d/(1000*60*60))%24;
var minutesround=Math.floor(minutes);
var hoursround=Math.round(hours);
var endtime = 12;

alert(hours);
alert(minutes);
```

If anyone is able to spot a better way of doing this, or can suggest anything it would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks,
Simon

Comment: moment.js, makes it way more easy to deal with dates in js (http://momentjs.com/)

Comment: `setHours(12)` returns the number of milliseconds, not the date

Comment: I was also looking at `dates.js` but ideally wanting to write this with a few lines of code.

Comment: Use `getHours()`, not `getTime()`

Comment: getHours() does not also get your minutes, I can split the two values but then it becomes more complicated as it will be using it as a number. Arun's answer did the trick

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
var d = new Date(), midDay = new Date();

midDay.setHours(12);
midDay.setMinutes(0);
midDay.setSeconds(0);

if(d > midDay) {
    midDay.setDate(midDay.getDate() + 1)
}
var diff = (midDay.getTime() - d.getTime()) / 1000;

var hrs = parseInt(diff / 3600);
diff = diff % 3600;

var minutes = parseInt(diff / 60);
console.log(hrs, minutes)
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/ZV442/)